# Need guidance trying to setup a variable amount with stripe using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm new to node and javascript so please excuse me. This is what I have right now, just copied it from the Stripe docs. I'm confused as to what I'm supposed to do with the commented token function. I was using the simple Stripe configuration and got everything working perfectly but I decided that I want to allow a custom amount to be set by the user via an input field. Any help to guide me in that direction would be awesome.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>

<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_...',
  image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function(token) {
    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
    // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
  }
});

document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:
  handler.open({
    name: 'Demo Site',
    description: '2 widgets',
    amount: 2000
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
</script>
```

And here's my server-side code (stripe.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_...');

router.post('/charge', function(req, res, next) {
    var token = req.body.stripeToken;
    var chargeAmount = req.body.chargeAmount;
    var charge = stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 2000,
      currency: "usd",
      source: token
    }, function(err, charge) {
      if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(req.body);
      res.redirect('/users/dashboard');
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) does not send the amount and currency to the backend server -- it only uses the `amount` and `currency` parameters for display purposes.

This is by design. Outside of scenarios where the amount should explicitly be set by the paying customer (e.g. if you're accepting donations), you cannot trust an amount that is sent by the customer's browser as it would be very easy to modify it.

But in this case, it sounds like you do want the amount to be set by the customer. So you need to do this:

1. In your client-side (frontend) code, make sure that the amount is sent along with the token returned by Checkout.

   Here is a simple example of a form where the amount is set by the customer: https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/g2ufa8xr/. In this form, the amount will be sent as the `amount` POST parameter, along with the `stripeToken` and `stripeEmail` parameters returned by Checkout.
2. In your server-side (backend) code, use the amount in the [charge creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge).

   This is easy, simply retrieve the parameter and use it as the value of the `amount` parameter of the charge creation request:

   ```
   var token = req.body.stripeToken;
   var amount = req.body.amount;
   var charge = stripe.charges.create({
     amount: amount,
     currency: "usd",
     source: token
   }, function(err, charge) {
       ...
   }
   ```

As a side note, please never share your secret API key publicly, even if it's just a test key. You should roll out a new key ASAP. You can do this by heading to your dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys and clicking the "recycle" icon next to the key you want to replace.